# Microsoft Test Manager Configurations

Tags: .net, microsoft-test-manager

I understand that I can create my own configuration variables and my own configurations.  The default variables are Operating System and Browser.  This is describing the environment configuration.

My software has a small config tool for setting various features on and off.  Are these variables suitable for test manager configurations?

Currently we are simply listing the settings that are required as the first step in the test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - having looked at MSDN it states that these configuration variables describe the environment such as OS, RAM etc and are not intended for config variables of the system under test.